# How to sort out first row in a list

Tags: python, replace

I would like to sort out the first row of a given list.
I've been already tried to use python "replace" to remove the second row.
But the problem is that the replace function seems not work at all.
Here is the regular expression I used: replace(r'^ //.*$','')

Here is the list:

```
//SA/... //short_message/Saint/...
//SS-SA/... //long_message/wonder-girl/...
```

here is the output I am expecting:

```
//SA/...
//SS-SA/...
```

Comment: Second row or second column?

Comment: `str.replace()` doesn't take a regular expression as argument: it takes two strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = ["1 12","3 12","2 12"] # space separated 
n = [x.split()[0] for x in l]
print sorted(n)
```